# Prefab random rotation in editor

Tags: unity, unityscript

Is it possible to automacicaly random rotate pefab during placement in editor in unity 4.5.3?

I can make it autorotate in game(at start) but I want it to be visible in editor and at fixed rotation after placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!
Attribute `[ExecuteInEditMode]` does what I want

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class RandomRotation : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        this.transform.Rotate(0, MyRandom.Rotate(this.GetInstanceID()), 0);
        this.transform.localScale = MyRandom.Scale (this.GetInstanceID(), 0.4f, 1f);
        Debug.Log("Editor");

#else
        Debug.Log("Game");
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't editor scripting in unity pretty cool